# Accessing Gradle global properties in buildscript block

Tags: gradle

My main Gradle script:

```
buildscript {scriptHandler->
    apply from: "......./repositories.gradle", to: scriptHandler
}
```

loads repositories.gradle script:

```
repositories{
    maven {
        url = "myURL"
        credentials {
            username repositoryReadUsername
            password repositoryReadPassword
        }
    }
}
```

Values repositoryReadUsername, repositoryReadPassword are defined in gradle.properties file.

I am getting error:

> A problem occurred evaluating script.
>
> > Could not get unknown property 'repositoryReadUsername' for Credentials [username: null] of type
> >     org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultPasswordCredentials_Decorated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be not possible to use this properties within applied buildscript. [Here is](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-properties-are-not-available-when-applying-external-script-in-buildscript/8678) mostly the same question and the answer is:

> Script plugins aren't currently affected by the buildscript section of
>   the build scripts they get applied to. (Actually, it's questionable
>   whether subproject build scripts should be affected by the buildscript
>   sections of parent build scripts, even though that's the way it
>   currently is.) What you can do is to move the reusable parts of the
>   buildscript section into its own script plugin

So it seems, that you have to declare your repository out of scriptplugins or provide credentials without getting them from properties file.